# Нужны ли запятые, и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые в этом предложении и почему? Может ли кто-нибудь грамотно обосновать правило? 
Но как быть, если вся твоя жизнь(,) с самого рождения(,) непрерывно связана с сильным, талантливым, разносторонним человеком?

Answer (score 1):

Но как быть, если вся твоя жизнь,с самого рождения, непрерывно связана с сильным, талантливым, разносторонним человеком?

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Семантический показатель: Обособление уточняющего обстоятельственного определения: вся твоя жизнь, с самого рождения.

2) Интонационно-структурная грамматика. Центральной частью предложения является однородный ряд определений, требующий перечислительной интонации. Поэтому интонационная структура предложения ориентируется именно на эту цель, а в этом случае "с самого рождения" удобно отнести на второй план для уменьшения объема основного сообщения.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь обособление контекстуально. Можно рассматривать "с самого рождения" как уточнение к "вся жизнь". Вся = с рождения. Но можно и по-другому, без запятых.

*Но как быть, если вся твоя жизнь с самого рождения непрерывно связана с сильным, талантливым, разносторонним человеком?*

Определяем точку отсчета: вся с рождения; вся со школы; вся с юности и т.д.

Comment: Вся жизнь - это и есть вся жизнь до настоящего момента, а вся жизнь с юности - это только часть жизни.

Comment: "Всю" можно понимать как "отсюда и до конца", "вся жизнь" = "вся сознательная жизнь" = "вся жизнь с юности". Значений много. Например: "Отдал всю жизнь детям" - это же не с младенчества ("весь" указывает на высшую степень проявления состояния, признака, качества, обозначенного существительным).

Comment: Здесь дело в семантической несочетаемости в пределах одной фразы, а не в смысле какого-то обобщения.